# Multi select picklist to picklist

Tags: picklist, administration, data-loader

I am trying to move from Multi-select picklist to a single select picklist. What steps should I take? I am thinking(not clear yet) there is a data load involved. Should I leave the existing data with multipicklist values, hide the multi-select picklist and go with single-select picklist for future records?

Please let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

1. Backup your data (export with Data Loader)
2. Convert field from Picklist (Multi-select) to Picklist. It will probably clear all the values in the existing records from that field. If you check the option to **not** strictly enforce picklist values - data loader should allow you to upload previous values and you'll see field values like "Value1; Value2", even though it won't be valid value.
3. Consider how to cleanup records - either manually or with some import process

Of course I'd recommend trying it out on full copy sandbox first, then in production. Also check if no code / workflows are based on the existing field (because the system won't allow you to change it so easily)

Another option is to leave current field, hide it and create a new one, but that is an easy approach that is just keeping mess in the system.